# Can I make a 64bit driver and use it only on my PC without buying a certificate?

Tags: c++, driver

Using Visual Studio Community can I sign my driver to be able to install and run it on my local machine windows 64bit only and use it everyday?

Comment: Did you consider installing and using Linux on your computer? It is developer friendly, and you don't need any certificate or permission from outside to write a driver for it; and you'll have many examples of free software for inspiration

Comment: Also relevant: [How do I create a self-signed certificate for code signing on Windows?](//stackoverflow.com/q/84847)

Comment: The research for this dupe made me even more glad I'm on Linux. Why would I have to buy a certificate to run code I trust? Microsoft being Microsoft...